# Given two arrays A1,A2, return if for a given X , there is a pair of ai∈Ai such that a1+a2=X ((n log()))

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, data-structure

The question is fairly easy to understand, the problem is i need the algorithm running time to be (n log()), which i couldn't achieve.

Given two arrays with positive integers,lets call them A1,A2
return if for a given X(the input) , there is a pair of ai∈Ai such that a1+a2=X.

For example A1 = { 22,4,5 }
            A2 = { 11,3,9 }
For X = 7 we return true, since 3+4=7
(4 its our a1, and 3 its our a2).

Thanks.

Comment: Sort them $O(n\ln(n))$. Then $A_1\times A_2$ is a part of a rectangular grid. Take the 'center point' $(a,b)={}$(middle of $A_1$, middle of $A_2$). This point divides the grid in four rectangles. Evaluate $a+b$ and compare to $X$. The result excludes one of the four rectangles. Solve the problem in each of them recursively. This recursion takes $\log_{4/3}(n)$.

Comment: so if im using the example above, the grid is:
(3,4)(3,5)(3,22)
(9,4)(9,5)(9,22)
(11,4)(11,5)(11,22)
and the center point is (9,5)?

Comment: Yes. The idea is just like [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), but since the problem is two-dimensional, then we divide in four.

Comment: okay i will work on that, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sort both arrays, in $O(n\ln n)$.
You have two pointers.  One points to the first number in $A_1$, and the other starts at the last number in $A_2$.
Repeat:
If the sum is less than $X$, move the first pointer to the next number in $A_1$.  If the sum is greater, move the second pointer to the previous number in $A_2$.
If there is a solution, then the first pointer will, at some time, point to the right number in $A_1$.  The second pointer will then come down to the right number in $A_2$.
The first pointer won't pass the right number in $A_1$ before the right number in $A_2$ is reached, and vice versa.

Comment: WOW! thanks very much !
should i use quicksort?

Comment: I suppose so, whatever is standard.

Comment: can you please explain why sorting both arrays is O(n ln(n))?

Comment: do you think i should move the pointers recursively  or using iteration?